# try to create item from other item via button_to new_item_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am completely new at ROR and trying to build an application.
I try to create (and after that view) a customer out of a partner. I need to open the customer form first because it needs additional info before final create.

**partner form, show.html.erb:**

```
<%=  button_to 'Create Customer', 
new_customer_path(partner_id: @partner.id), :method => :get %>
```

**customer controller**:

```
def new
  # @customer = Customer.new
  partner = Partner.find(params[:partner_id])
  @customer = Customer.new(partner_id: @partner.id)
end
```

the definition of the `partner_id` field in the customer table (i'm not sure about either), happened after the facts, doing an `add_column`:

```
class AddPartnerIdtoCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :customers, :partner_id, :integer, references: :partners

    add_index :customers, :partner_id
  end
end
```

I have been trying to change all the time and keep getting errors! With what i wrote here, the error I get:

```
Couldn't find Partner without an ID
```

Can someone please help? And explain what and why it goes wrong?
Thank you!!!!

Comment: What are the `params` that are generated for that action?

Answer (score 0):

Just change `button_to` to `link_to`.

```
<%= link_to 'Create Customer', 
new_customer_path(partner_id: @partner.id), class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

`button_to` generates a form, and sending it as empty params.

```
<form class="button_to" method="get" action="/categories/new?plan=1">
  <input type="submit" value="Create Customer">
</form>
```

`link_to` generates actual anchor tag with params.

```
<a href="/categories/new?plan=1">Create Customer</a>
```